# Having trouble performing multiplication on data from xml

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, google-api, xmldocument

Hi I'm having trouble multiplying data retrieved from google finance api. I know that what I'm doing now is wrong so I would like some pointers on how to go about doing that and some examples on that as well.

```
    string url = "http://www.google.com/ig/api?stock=" + Server.UrlEncode(symbol1.Text);
     XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
     xdoc.Load(url);
     currentPrice1.Text = GetData(xdoc, "last");
     int quantity = 50;
     int currentPrice = int.Parse(currentPrice1.Text);
     int totalValue = quantity * currentPrice;
```

**GetData method**

```
private string GetData(XmlDocument doc2, string strElement)
{

    XmlNodeList xnodelist5 = doc2.GetElementsByTagName(strElement);
    XmlNode xnode5 = xnodelist5.Item(0);
    return Get_Attribute_Value(xnode5, "data");

}
```

**ERROR**
[image: ERROR]

Comment: Please show us the error when you do multiplication

Comment: Yup, I added that thanks for reminding me that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be value of *data* attribute is non-numeric or not specified. Use TryParse method or wrap up your code with try..catch.. block.

```
 decimal currentPrice;
 if(decimal.TryParse(currentPrice1.Text, out currentPrice))
  {
     //
   }
```

Or use `int.TryParse` if value of data attribute is integer.

Comment: Thanks man, you're a life saver. The data attribute is decimal.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the print screen of your code curentPrice1.Text might having a null or empty or some non-numeric

So please do

```
int currentPrice = 0;

if(!string.IsEmptyOrNull(currentPrice1.Text))
{
   int price = 0;
   if(int.TryParse(currentPrice1.Text, out price))
   {
       currentPrice = price ;
   }
}
```